# Django models - how to make field from one model be dependable on field in another model (which is foreign key)?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

I'm new to Django and I'm not sure how to deal with folowing problem:

I have models:

```
class Season(models.Model):
    number_of_episodes = models.IntegerField()
class Episode(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season)
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

Episode number should not only be unique in season but also smaller than season's number_of_episodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the episode number to be unique in season, you can use [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together). This means that to for every value of one of the field, there can be only one row with a value in the other field. That would look about this:

```
class Season(models.Model):
    number_of_episodes = models.IntegerField()
class Episode(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (season, number)
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season)
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

I don't think you can use django models to enforce that the episode number should be less than season.number_of_episodes, but you can do that in a overridden save-method. Something like this:

```
class Season(models.Model):
    number_of_episodes = models.IntegerField()

class Episode(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (season, number)
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season)
    number = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.number > season.number_of_episodes:
            return #Don't save
        else:
            super(Episode, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Note that this only jumps out of the save-method if the episode-number is incorrect. You will probably raise a exception instead.

Comment: This works fine, but I would like to add another field to Episode:
actors = models.manyToManyField(Actor)

unfortunately when I do, it raises exception when I try to add episode with too high number: "'Episode' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used."

Do you know why it is and what can I do?

Comment: Maybe you first call save on a object, and then add a actor on it. If you add a episode with a episode-number that is too high, the model won't save (if you use the code above) and you will get that error-message. This is because ManyToMany fields need a object with a primary-key, and the object gets a primary-key the first time it is saved. To fix you have to bail out if the episode-number is too high. For instance you can throw an exception (instead of just returning) and handle that somewhere.

Comment: Where should I handle exception?